# Default controller name is removed on browser refresh (CodeigniterPHP/Nginx issue?)

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

For all pages in my codeigniter app except my default controller, `main.php`, when I refresh the browser the url isn't affected as one would expect.

However when I refresh the browser at "http://localhost/main", the `main` part is stripped off the url. So the browser bar shows just "http://localhost".

Totally lost on where to start with this but was just wondering if anyone has come across this before...?

Here's what I think could be the relevant part of my nginx.conf (if Nginx is the problem).

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^(/main(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;  
}
```

Note that changing the bracketed code to this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /main permanent;
```

results in the error message `The webpage at http://localhost/main has resulted in too many redirects.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I answered my own question. Simply commenting out the nginx.conf code that I showed corrects the problem.

So just do this ([says Bo Jackson](http://www.gunaxin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Bo-Jackson.jpg)):

```
#if ($request_uri ~* ^(/main(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
#{
#  rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;  
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to route your request to the index.php bootstrap so you can remove the index.php from your url in CodeIgniter you probably should try using this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i think my codeigniter my config/config.php file is already removing the index.php part.

Comment: can also do this in `server{}` part of nginx.conf: `# removes trailing "index" from all controllers
            if ($request_uri ~* index/?$){
                rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
            }`